# PeerConnectionFactory in Android Studio 2 has no methods

Tags: java, android-studio, webrtc

After adding `compile 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'` to my build.gradle file I try to init `PeerConnectionFactory`, but this class has no any useful methods.

[image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHgXT.png)

Answer (score 2):

The last version `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.21217`

You can init by following codes

```
PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.Builder optionBuilder = 
    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(/* Put context here */);
optionBuilder.setEnableInternalTracer(true);
optionBuilder.setFieldTrials("WebRTC-FlexFEC-03/Enabled/");
optionBuilder.setEnableVideoHwAcceleration(true);
PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(optionBuilder.createInitializationOptions());
```

Comment: `setEnableVideoHwAcceleration` not found in v. 1.0.30039. I'm periodically getting GLES20 error: 1282, was trying disabling hardware acceleration as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118620/webrtc-application-crash-on-samsung-galaxy-j1-4g, but can't find this parameter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use an specific version like: `compile 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.20198'`

And then make sure you rebuild your project (not only refresh gradle, since it might not be enough for the autocomplete to work).

In your screenshot, it looks like you are trying to autocomplete outside of any method. Since Android Studio tries to only show you valid stuff, it won't display the other methods unless you write it on a valid context (i.e.: inside of some method's implementation).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not help. P.S.: add screenshot with writing valid context