# webRTC application crash on Samsung Galaxy J1 4G

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, samsung-galaxy

I am working on Video Calling Android application, where video call works on devices such as Nexus 4, Moto g2 , Moto g3 , Moto e. But when I initiate call on Samsung Galaxy J1 4G it crashes.

Here is the stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: gl_surface: EglRenderer
Process: com.testvideo, PID: 30509
java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1282
    at org.webrtc.GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error(GlUtil.java:29)
    at org.webrtc.GlShader.useProgram(GlShader.java:118)
    at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.prepareShader(GlRectDrawer.java:195)
    at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.drawOes(GlRectDrawer.java:118)
    at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawTexture(VideoFrameDrawer.java:38)
    at org.webrtc.VideoFrameDrawer.drawFrame(VideoFrameDrawer.java:205)
    at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.renderFrameOnRenderThread(EglRenderer.java:585)
    at org.webrtc.EglRenderer.bridge$lambda$0$EglRenderer(EglRenderer.java)
    at org.webrtc.EglRenderer$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I went through this question [Android WebRtc Local Video Stream is not displaying on marshmallow but works on lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528908/android-webrtc-local-video-stream-is-not-displaying-on-marshmallow-but-works-on), but it is little bit different. In my case application crashes only on Samsung Galaxy J1 4G 
OS : 5.1.1
Model: SMJ120G

I am using following libs/dependencies:

- org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+
- fi.vtt.nubomedia:utilities-android:1.0.2@aar

It will be great if someone can give any suggestion.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I also get the same error periodically in org.webrtc v. 1.0.30039. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was related to hardware acceleration. When I disabled hardware acceleration issue got resolved.
`PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals` 
Here I passed false for hardwareAccelration.

Comment: There's no such thing anymore in org.webrtc v. 1.0.30039.